# Should I remove the as attribute in the link tag when preloading LCP images to get a high priority?

Tags: google-chrome, core-web-vitals

When preloading LCP images, should the `as="image"` attribute be removed to force the priority of Google Chrome to high? It is my understanding that the priority defaults to low.

Instead of this -

```
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="cool-lcp-image.avif" />
```

Should it be -

```
<link rel="preload" href="cool-lcp-image.avif" />
```

Comment: Are you sure removing that removing the `is` attribute has this affect? It's definitely not _supposed_ to have this affect (given that the attribute is required), and in my testing preload doesn't work at all if I remove the `is` attribute.

Comment: @PhilipWalton just realized this is an old article but https://medium.com/reloading/preload-prefetch-and-priorities-in-chrome-776165961bbf "Preloaded resources without an “as” will otherwise be requested with the same priority as async XHR (so High)."

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that post is out of date. I mentioned this to Addy and he said he'll update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `as` attribute should not be removed. If it is removed, the browser will not preload the resource.

Generally speaking, a preloaded request will be one of the first requests made, regardless of resource priority - so altering resource priority shouldn't be a primary concern. (There also isn't a good mechanism for doing this at the moment - though [priority hints](https://wicg.github.io/priority-hints/) would change this.)

If it's an in-viewport image it will have [high priority](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bCDuq9H1ih9iNjgzyAL0gpwNFiEP4TZS-YLRp_RuMlc/edit?hl=en&forcehl=1); if it's a out-of-viewport image it will have low priority.